# Reverse UIView without its subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to reverse an UIView with some subviews on it (UILabels,Buttons, and so on...)

I'm doing this by

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
```

Is there an easy way to prevent the subviews from being reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the same transform to all the subviews, so that they're reversed twice:

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
self.transform = t;
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
    subview.transform = t;
}
```

Comment: This total did it!
Had the same approach but used the wrong `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`

Answer (score 0):

```
///Reverse the Tabs from RightToLeft
public func rightToLeft() {
    let t = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: -1, y: -1)
    self.transform = t
    self.subviews.forEach { (subview) in
        subview.transform = t
    }
}

///Reverse the Tabs from LeftToRight
public func leftToRight() {
    let t = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    self.transform = t
    self.subviews.forEach { (subview) in
        subview.transform = t
    }
}
```